# How can I get my Ui Buttons to switch colors in Unity?

Tags: user-interface, button, unity-game-engine, colors

I'm working on a basic Match three in Unity using only the UI. For the objects to match I'm using the UI buttons and having the objects be different colors. For having the objects switch palaces I have a method that switches the color of the buttons. My difficulty is in calling the method upon pressing the buttons.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class match : MonoBehaviour {

public float time = 30.0f;
public float _score;
public GameObject pausePanel;
private Color[] colors = new Color[3];
//public Button[] buttons;
private Image[] image = new Image[16];
public Image im1;
public Image im2;
public Image im3;
public Image im4;
public Image im5;
public Image im6;
public Image im7;
public Image im8;
public Image im9;
public Image im10;
public Image im11;
public Image im12;
public Image im13;
public Image im14;
public Image im15;
public Image im16;
public Image b;
public Image c;
public Image temp;

void Start () {
    _score = 0.0f;
    colors [0] = Color.red;
    colors [1] = Color.blue;
    colors [2] = Color.green;
    image [0] = im1;
    image [1] = im2;
    image [2] = im3;
    image [3] = im4;
    image [4] = im5;
    image [5] = im6;
    image [6] = im7;
    image [7] = im8;
    image [8] = im9;
    image [9] = im10;
    image [10] = im11;
    image [11] = im12;
    image [12] = im13;
    image [13] = im14;
    image [14] = im15;
    image [15] = im16;
}

void Update () {

    time -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (time <= 0) {
        time = 0.0f;
    }

    if (time == 0 && _score == 0) {
        pausePanel.SetActive (true);
    }
    AssignColor (); 
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 30, 20), "" + time.ToString ("0"));
    GUI.Box (new Rect (85, 410, 30, 20), "" + _score.ToString ("0"));
}

void AssignColor()
{
    foreach (Image i in image) {
        int colornum = Random.Range (0, colors.Length);
        if(i.color == Color.white){
            i.color = colors[colornum];
        }
    }

}

public void getButton(Image i)
{
    if (b == null) {
        b = i;
    } 
    else if (c == null) {
        c = i;
    }

    if (b != null && c != null) {
        Swap(b, c);
        b = null;
        c = null;
    }
}

void Swap(Image ac, Image bc)
{
    //Image temp;
    temp.color = ac.color;
    ac.color = bc.color;
    bc.color = temp.color;

}
}
```

I have all my buttons in my Inspector able to activate getButton, and the image are being taking by Image b or Image C upon pressing the button but they are not switching colors.

Comment: I would be surprised that you do not declare a list or array of images like List<Image> images, but rather Image im1,2,N, though off topic.

Comment: I could do that later after everything else I need to do is done.

Comment: Presumably it's to take advantage of Unity's UI functionality where the user can drag and drop images into the properties through the inspector. I'm sure there is a way to do this with an array or list, but it would be a bit more work (but also less maintenance!)

Comment: @Eraph You can literally declare a array and have the same drag and drop functionality. Where as the only difference is that your new array based images are also collapsible.

Comment: FYI do **not** use "ongui" for any reason, it is being dropped by unity. Use only the "new" (ie 5 yrs old) Unity.UI.  Note it is incredibly easier to use.

Answer (score -1):

In `OnGUI()` you can use the `GUI.color = Color.Blue;` to tint everything following thereafter to in blue. To make items look normal again (e.g. if you only want to tint 1 UI element in a certain color), just use `GUI.color = Color.White`

```
void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.color = Color.Blue;// Tints everything hereafter in blue
    GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 30, 20), "" + time.ToString ("0"));

    GUI.color = Color.White;// Tints everything hereafter normally
    GUI.Box (new Rect (85, 410, 30, 20), "" + _score.ToString ("0"));
}
```